# Other Prores flavors in AVFoundation

Tags: swift, avfoundation, quicktime, qtkit

Since apple has decided that QTKit is no more, and AVFoundation appears to only support Prores 4444 and 422 flavors, how are developers supposed to write modern software that can handle 4444XQ, 422lt, and 422 proxy? Would love to know if anyone has a way to handle these codecs that isn't relying on deprecated technology.